# vector<unique_ptr> copy constructible?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I am confused about:

```
cout << is_copy_constructible<int>::value
     << is_copy_constructible<unique_ptr<int>>::value
     << is_copy_constructible<vector<unique_ptr<int>>>::value;
```

I expected `100`, but got `101` with gcc 4.9.1 and clang 3.4.2

How can `vector<unique_ptr>` be copy constructible (or assignable for that matter) while keeping correct `unique_ptr` semantics?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803403/stdunordered-mapt-stdunique-ptru-copyable-gcc-bug/25803813#25803813

Comment: Or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404108/issue-with-is-copy-constructible