# Is object construction expression well-formed even if that construction cannot be compiled?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, well-formed

Suppose we have a *non-copyable* type `X`:

```
struct X
{
    X(X&&) = default;
    X(const X&) = delete;
}
```

Then, naturally, we cannot copy a container having `X` as value type:

```
std::set<X> v;
std::set<X> v2{v}  // error
```

My question is, whether the expression that involves such a copy is *well-formed*? For instance, the following expression compiles:

```
sizeof( std::set<X>{v} )
```

I am asking since I run into the following problem:

```
std::cout << std::is_copy_constructible_v< X >;
std::cout << std::is_copy_constructible_v< std::set<X> >;
```

Which prints out `01`. It's a bit counter-intuitive that `std::set<X>` is "reported" being *copy-constructible* when in fact it is not (by means of that its copy constructor cannot be called).

Comment: `is_copy_constructible_v` only checks the ["immediate context"](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta.unary.prop#8.sentence-4), which means it does not look into the constructor body.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803403/stdunordered-mapt-stdunique-ptru-copyable-gcc-bug

Comment: @cpplearner Good catch, haven't found that question. Suggest closing this one as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

That comes from a problem you have, when your container shall support incomplete types. You cannot do both

- Support incomplete types
- SFINAE out the special member functions based on copy-ability of the value type

If you support incomplete types, you cannot check in the declaration of the copy constructor if that type is copyable (since it could be incomplete at that point). So, you can always instantiate the copy constructor. But if you do, that will fail in evaluated contextes.

There is a good article on this: https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/02/05/vector-is-copyable-except-when-its-not/

Comment: For a language-lawyer question, you are expected to provide quotes from the standard text. An external article is definitely not appropriate here.